# How to install plugin for chartjs in javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My goal is to add an average line to my barchart.

I downloaded the github repo for this plugin [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) and added to my wordpress theme in path:

```
/Users/Name/Downloads/public_html/wp-content/themes/Total/assets/js/chartjs-plugin-annotation-master/src/annotation.js
```

Next, I call it in my html:

```
<script src="annotation.js"></script>
```

Lastly, I call it my chartjs script:

```
<canvas id="Chart"></canvas>
                            <script>
                            var charts_plugin = chartjs-plugin-annotation.js;
                            var canvas_2 = document.getElementById("Chart");
                            var ctx_2 = canvas_2.getContext('2d');
                            var Chart = new Chart(ctx_2, {
                                    plugins: [charts_plugin],
                                type: 'bar',
                                data: {
                                  labels: <?php echo json_encode($arr_macd_dates_formated); ?>,
                                  datasets: [
                                    {
                                      label: '<?php echo $str_macd, $arr_macd_name[0]  ; ?>',
                                      backgroundColor: ["#faae00"],
                                      data: <?php echo json_encode($arr_macd_diff); ?>
                                    }
                                  ]
                                },
                                options: {
                                  legend: { display: false },
                                  title: {
                                    display: true,
                                    },
                                        annotation: {
                                          annotations: [{
                                            type: 'line',
                                            mode: 'horizontal',
                                            scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                                            value: 5,
                                            borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                                            borderWidth: 4,
                                            label: {
                                              enabled: false,
                                              content: 'Test label'
                                            }
                                          }]
                                        }
                                }
                            });

                            </script>
```

Here is how I call my chart js :

```
function custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chart-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.1/chart.js', array(), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts');
```

This does not call the plugin:

```
var charts_plugin = chart-js-annotation.js;
```

makes the chart disappear.

Comment: Please provide your full HTML file or a minimal "working" example.

Comment: Maybe easier to post link to my site: https://signal-invest.com/tick/?ticker=aapl

Comment: Did you check the errors you get: `[Error] Refused to execute https://signal-invest.com/tick/annotation.js as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.`

Comment: Oh I never noticed this tbh.

Comment: også lad være med at skrive kommentar på danks :p (bare en joke) - Just asked him not write comments in Danish in code :)

Comment: Haha, I knew you were danish too, mate. That name tho :D

Comment: hehe yeah pretty easy XD But æ,ø, and å can cause trouble in code from time to time so just in general don't :) But check the error and try and fix it from there :)

Comment: where do you see the error though? I cant find it

Comment: in the web browser dev interface

Comment: what browser do you use

Comment: Google Chrome mate

Comment: Right-click and hit show page source / inspect element (or whatever it is called in chrome) it will give you a lot of info and you should see a warning with a red "stop" sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `annotation.js` is not in the same directory as the HTML file.

Try

```
<script src="path/to/annotation.js"></script>
```

Example

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/Total/assets/js/chartjs-plugin-annotation-master/src/annotation.js"></script>
```

Also

`var charts_plugin = chartjs-plugin-annotation.js;`

Try changing this line to
`var charts_plugin = path/to/annotation.js;`

Comment: So weird, the entire graph disappears when I add the var charts_plugin = path/to/annotation.js;

Comment: path/to/ is just a placeholder. replace with your path to chart.js

Comment: I replaced that but when I call the variable in the plugins in chartjs, the graph disappears again.